# Input variables in Dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave

I am reading through the [Dataweave documentation](http://mulesoft.github.io/data-weave/#_variables) and am stumped with the example below.

The documentation says

> Input directives allow you to make any number of input sources
>   available in global variables, which can then be referenced in any
>   part of the Transform’s body. To reference one of these, you can just
>   call it by the name you defined in the directive.

Then follows up with the example below

```
%dw 1.0
%input in0
%output application/xml
---
payload
```

My questions:

In which scopes will mule look for the variable in0? Payload, Flow, Session or something else, and in which order?

In this example, where is in0 used?  How does it help in this example?

Why would I need an input variable? Dataweave seems to allow flowVars.hello.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the example doesn't match the text. That example should be:

```
%dw 1.0
%input in0
%output application/xml
---
in0
```

By default the input (however you named it) will be the payload. You can just be explicit and optionally also define the payload as an input directive in the header, although this isn’t required.

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/xml
%output application/xml
---
{
  a: payload
}
```

Further in the documentation there are better examples:

> CSV Input Directive When defining an input of type CSV, there are a
>   few optional parameters you can add to the input directive to
>   customize how the data will be parsed.
>
> header: boolean that defines if the first line in the data contains
>   headers
>
> separatorChar: character that separates fields, ',' by default
>
> quoteChar: character that defines quoted text, " " by default
>
> escapeChar: character that escapes quotes, / by default
>
> A CSV input directive with custom parameters set looks like this:
>
> %input in0 application/csv header=true separatorChar=; When
>   header=true you can then access the fields within the input anywhere
>   by name. Ex: in0.userName.
>
> When header=false you must access the fields by index, referencing
>   first the entry and then the field, Ex: in0[107][2]

Comment: So the first variable after %input will always be giving a alias to the payload ? so in this example %input in0 application/csv ; in0 is an alias for payload which should be of type application/csv ... is my understanding correct ? Also any clues why they choose to come up with a whole new language rather than just build a DSL off groovy or something ? How does one debug these scripts ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you would not need to declare anything with %input directive. By default payload, flowVars, inbound/outbound properties, sessionVars etc are accessible in dataweave like they are in MEL.

MEL is same as Java, anything that you can write in java to debug (System.out) you can do it in MEL too.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
    GENDER: payload.gender,
    test:flowVars.test,
    testIp:inboundProperties.testIp,
    testOp:outboundProperties.testOp
}
```

Look at this example for multiple inputs -
[Multiple Inputs](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-examples#multiple-inputs)